# Can't delete file from web interface of owncloud

Tags: owncloud, shared-hosting

I have own instance of own cloud. With latest stable version 6.0.1.

If i delete some files from web - after page refresh they are back.

If i delete some files from client (1.5.0) under linux, in activity i see this files with action = "301 Moved Permanently".

Any idea, how to delete, and what info i must provide for problem solving?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my problem by reinstalling owncloud.
While reinstalling, i get few problems, that solved by creating new php.ini file in installing folder:

```
# Magic Quotes is enabled. ownCloud requires that it is disabled to work properly.
magic_quotes_gpc = off
magic_quotes_runtime = off
magic_quotes_sybase = off


# PHP PDO module is not installed.
extension=pdo.so
extension=pdo_sqlite.so
extension=sqlite.so
extension=pdo_mysql.so
```